# How to remove default padding from material ui List Item?

Tags: material-ui

Material ui add default padding on List and ListItem how to remove it ? 
Any help or direction to resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can override the `root` class of the `ListItem` component and pass the padding you want.

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  },

  item: {
    padding: 0
  }
});

function SimpleList(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <List component="nav">
        <ListItem button classes={{ root: classes.item }}>
          <ListItemText primary="Item 01" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button classes={{ root: classes.item }}>
          <ListItemText primary="Item 02" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button classes={{ root: classes.item }}>
          <ListItemText primary="Item 03" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See [working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/3124lnq83m).

Comment: @PanayiotisGeorgiou You are welcome ! Don't hesitate to mark the answer as accepted then ;)

Answer (score 13):

For anyone else coming here the easy way to remove the default padding from the list is to use the **disablePadding** prop on the **List Component**.

https://material-ui.com/api/list/

[image]

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
    import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'
    import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText'
    
    function Sidebar() {
      return (
        <List disablePadding>
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemText>Home</ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemText>Billing</ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemText>Settings</ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      )
    }
    
    export default Sidebar
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're just using a `ListItem` component, you can use the `disableGutters` (Boolean) property to disable the left and right padding, as seen from the API documentation: https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/

```js
<ListItem disableGutters={true} button={true} key='Home' component={Link} to={"/"} selected={'/' === pathname}>
   <ListItemIcon><Home /></ListItemIcon>
   <ListItemText primary='Home' />
</ListItem>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! 